# You know me best for being magic, but I can also mean a term of time... what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

Can someone help me with the following riddle?

> You know me best for being magic, but I can also mean a term of time... what am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is

> spell

Because you can

> cast a spell, or have a short spell of bad weather.

Answer (score 0):

Answer's already been given, but here's an alternate:

> Illusion

It's clearly magic and...

> "Time is an illusion" - a quote often attributed to Albert Einstein